# C++ - LNK2001 error

Tags: c++

I wanted to try myself on a little C++ application, but I all the time get the LNK2001 error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please help me out?

```
  #ifndef CONTENTMANAGER_H
    #define CONTENTMANAGER_H

    #include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
    #include <map>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace sf;
    using namespace std;


    static class CONTENTMANAGER
    {
    public:
            static Texture getTexture(string textureName)
            {
                    if(textureMap.find(textureName) == textureMap.end())
                    {

                                    Texture texture;
                                    stringstream ss;
                                    ss<<"Texture"<<textureName<<".png";
                                    texture.loadFromFile(ss.str());
                                    textureMap.emplace(textureName, texture);
                                    return textureMap[textureName];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                            return textureMap[textureName];
                    }
            }

    private:
            static map<string,Texture> textureMap;
    };




    #endif
```

Errormessage: http://www.bilderhoster.net/safeforbilder/5mdt1tzc.png

Comment: What OS are you using? What are you compiling this with? Whats the full error message?

Comment: It would help to see the full error message.   Chances are that you are not compiling the code for the 'Texture' class function calls along with your project and/or not properly linking the library files that contain those definitions.

Comment: I have added my error message into my post

Comment: Add your error message as *text* to the question itself, not as an image offsite. There is absolutely no need for a graphic to show the error message. Use images only where there is no other way to demonstrate the issue. Unnecessary images waste data for mobile users, are difficult to read, and are often blocked by corporate proxy servers (meaning that the relevant content isn't available to those readers). Images are also not searchable, so the content of the error messages can't be found by a future reader searching for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: *"error altough I have done everything correctly"* - An odd assumption, no?

Comment: Was that the reason why I have gotten "-2" onto my Question? Also, thank you for telling me. I will change it.

Comment: @EdS. I am sorry - I wanted to say "I assume I have done everything correctly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a straightforward error with a lot of baggage in the error messge!

You have not defined the static member variable named 'textureMap'. You are effectively getting an undefined symbol error at link-time.

In a .cpp file, please define that variable. That should take care of your problem.